# trying to force a button click for a function

Tags: jquery

I have two functions both of which are image carousels, lets call them a and b.

a is the first you user sees and b is what the user sees when they click a button to expand the image carousel to full screen. I'm trying to get image carousel a to do the same thing as b when b is on top. I'd ideally like to just force a click next or prev for a when you click b (prev, next)

here is how I'm handling the next prev clicks.

```
 var handler = function () {
   ............
   ...........
      .......
    if ($(this).hasClass('prevButton')) {
      ............ ......
     }
  var handler_big = function () {
         ...........
           .......
    if ($(this).hasClass('prevButton_big')) {
      ............ ......
     }


  // how the button click is called 
     btn_big = $('#full_image .button'); //has class .nextButton_big .prevButton_big                                            
              btn_big.click(handler_big);


    btn = $('#container .button'); //has class .nextButton .prevButton
          btn.click(handler);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's **[`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** function.

```
btn.trigger('click');
```

Comment: thanks! how can I make the trigger click be .nextButton or .prevButton

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking.

Comment: when I do a btn.trigger('click'); my image car. looks to see if it has a class of .prevButton

Comment: @Wantingtolearn your handler is doing that logic, from the code example you gave.

Comment: try it is but btn.trigger('click'); isn't giving is a class .prev or .next